Blackwell's ordering and the algebraic structure of Blackwell's experiments in a book
I was reading an article in econometrica about Bayesain persuasion. The mathematics behind the proofs, all these techical definitions and lemma's in the appendicies made me wonder if there exeists any book that has all these ideas of Blackwell's theory about information structures gathered somehow. Does anyone have a clue about such a book in Blackwell's experimenets?

These notes by Tilman Börgers might be helpful. They are based on a chapter in the book by Blackwell and Girshick.

@MichaelGreinecker thanks....it might be helpful!
